# dense sets and which of the following are true??

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following statements are true??

a. If $A \subset Q$ such that $Q-A$ is finite then $A$ is dense in $R$.

b. There exists $A\subset Q$ such that $Q-A$ is infinite and $A$ is dense in $R$.

c. There exists a pair of disjoint subsets of $Q$ such that both of them are dense in $R$.

d. None of the above is a true statement.

Comment: @tattwamasi amrutam can you please contact on my email (in profile description) , i am preparing for iit jam this time (exam in feb) , hope you can help .thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a,b,c are all true, and so d is false.

b. We can take A to be the complement in $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$.

c. We can take the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ with even numerator and the complement (elements with odd numerator). These subsets are sense in $\mathbb Q$ and hence in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: In c., how can we take complement of $\Bbb Q$? We need two disjoint subsets of $\Bbb Q$ that are dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @VikrantDesai Thanks, I edited.